Running Selenium on Koyeb: Session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I have been trying to run a Python script that goes into a website using Selenium. Scrape some data and check with a text file if there has been anychanges. If there is a difference send a mail to desired mail adresses.
Now, this code works on my Macbook Pro M3Pro (Silicon).
At first I created this code with FireFox but after running into issues with using the code on Koyeb, I have decided that chrome would be a better option.
(Both Firefox and Chrome versions were succesfully running on my pc.)
But in the end I still couldn't get it working on Koyeb.
Here is the error I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 84, in <module>
    latestNews=getLatestNews()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 55, in getLatestNews
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /app/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/127.0.6533.119/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x562e0a5f96ca <unknown>
#1 0x562e0a2ca600 <unknown>
#2 0x562e0a302485 <unknown>
#3 0x562e0a2fe2f8 <unknown>
#4 0x562e0a348ce8 <unknown>
#5 0x562e0a33c643 <unknown>
#6 0x562e0a30cd31 <unknown>
#7 0x562e0a30d79e <unknown>
#8 0x562e0a5c125b <unknown>
#9 0x562e0a5c51f2 <unknown>
#10 0x562e0a5ae615 <unknown>
#11 0x562e0a5c5d82 <unknown>
#12 0x562e0a59325f <unknown>
#13 0x562e0a5e8e68 <unknown>
#14 0x562e0a5e9040 <unknown>
#15 0x562e0a5f849c <unknown>
#16 0x7fdcb0bd5609 start_thread

And here is my codes:
main.py:
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'

def send_email(subject, body, to_email):

    smtp_server = "smtp.zoho.eu"
    smtp_port = 587
    from_email = "<mail>"  
    password = "<password>" 

    # Create the email
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    # Attach the email body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    try:
        # Set up the server
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()  # Upgrade the connection to a secure encrypted SSL/TLS connection
        server.login(from_email, password)

        # Send the email
        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
        print("Email sent successfully to: "+to_email+" !")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send email: {e}")

    finally:
        server.quit()  # Close the connection to the server

def getLatestNews():
    
    # Start Selenium
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    driver.get("<LINK>")
    if((driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[4]/a").text)=="Select Language TR\nTR"):
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[4]/a").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[2]/div[8]/a").click()
        
    # Get the data from Web 
    latestNews = (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[3]/div[2]/div/a").text) + " " + (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[2]").text)+ " " + (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[2]/div/span").text) + " " + (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[2]/span").text)
    print(latestNews)
    driver.close()
    return latestNews
    
def is_changed(latestNews):
    f = open("latestNews.txt", "r")
    if(f.read()!=latestNews):
        f = open("latestNews.txt", "w")
        f.write(latestNews)
        f.close()
        return True
    f.close()
    return False
    
def mailDelivery(latestNews):
    mailList= ["mail@gmail.com","example@gmail.com","test@gmail.com","test@gmail.com","othertest@gmail.com"]
    for i in mailList:
        send_email("Topic", "Some text\n\n"+latestNews, i)
    
while(True):
    latestNews=getLatestNews()
    if (is_changed(latestNews)):
        mailDelivery(latestNews)
    else:
        print("No difference")
    time.sleep(3600)

requirements.txt:
selenium
Procfile:
web: python main.py
I have checked a lots of Stackoverflow questions and have applied lots of them. But the current version still does not work. And couldn't find anyone trying to run selenium on Koyeb.
Edit: I also want to mention that I am using the free plan on Koyeb. Which gives like really slow CPU and 512MB RAM

I believe the issue was caused by the low process power. I have fixed my issue by not using selenium and using API requests to achieve my goal.
